# What's the correct way to pass object pointers to functions that accept objects by reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

New to C++, but not to C. Previously I use to just have my functions accept object pointers, but I'm trying to learn the C++ way and get to grips with passing objects by reference.

Is there a *correct* way of passing an object pointer to a function that accepts the object by reference?

I made an example where I passed the dereferenced pointer to the method `foo()`, but I'm wondering if this is considered good C++ practice or whether I should be doing something else.

```
class Entity {
    public:
        int x;
        Entity(int y) {
            x = y;
        }
};

void foo(Entity& e) {
    std::cout << e.x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  
  Entity* e = new Entity(5);
  foo(*e);
}
```

Comment: This code looks OK to me, for what it's worth. Except that `foo` should probably take `const Entity& e`, seeing as it doesn't attempt to modify the object.

Comment: Yes, that works. But even better: `Entity e(5); foo(e);`.

Comment: Generally speaking, you would only pass a pointer if `NULL` is a valid argument.  If instead your function expects that its parameter is _always_ a valid object, then use a reference.

Answer (score 0):

When you're passing arguments by reference to functions you should mark them as `const` to tell yourself (and other programmers) that the function won't modify the argument passed in.

If you are modifying the contents then you wouldn't mark it as `const`.

```
class Entity {
public:
    int x;
    Entity(int y) {
        x = y;
    }
};

// pass arguments here by const reference since you're not modifying anything
void foo(const Entity& e) { 
    std::cout << e.x << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Entity* e = new Entity(5);
    foo(*e);
}
```